# Java ModelMapper - Flattening Entity to Array of Integers

Tags: java, modelmapper

I am attempting to use the excellent Java ModelMapper library to flatten my JPA entities to DTOs. One of the entities is a "ResourceItem" that has a many-to-many relationship with a "ResourceCategory" entity.

```
    @Entity
public class ResourceItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int ID;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "resources")
    private List<ResourceCategory> resourceCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "TagsResources")
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FileID")
    private FileResource file;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    public ResourceItem() {

    } }
```

and

```
@Entity
public class ResourceCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "Title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private List<ResourceItem> resources = new ArrayList<>();

    public ResourceCategory() {

    }
```

I am trying to flatten ResourceItem so that, instead of containing  an ArrayList of ResouceCategories, it instead has an ArrayList of Integers that merely references the ID values of the related ResouceCategories.

```
public class ResourceItemDTO {
private int ID;
private List<Integer> resourceCategoriesID = new ArrayList<>();
private List<TagDTO> tags = new ArrayList<>();
private String filePath;
private String name;}
```

I am testing it with the following:

```
@Test
public void testResourceItems() {
    List<ResourceCategory> cList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ResourceItem> iList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Tag> tList = new ArrayList<>();
    tList.add(new Tag(1, "Tag1"));
    tList.add(new Tag(2, "Tag2"));
    ResourceCategory cat = new ResourceCategory();
    ResourceItem itm1 = new ResourceItem(1, tList, new FileResource(1, "Path", "Caption"), "Name");
    ResourceItem itm2 = new ResourceItem(1, tList, new FileResource(2, "Path2", "Caption2"), "Name2");
    iList.add(itm1);
    iList.add(itm2);
    cat.setID(1);
    cat.setResources(iList);
    cList.add(cat);
    itm1.setResourceCategories(cList);
    itm2.setResourceCategories(cList);

    for (ResourceItem itm : iList) {
        assertThat(mapper.map(itm, ResourceItemDTO.class).getFilePath()).isEqualTo(itm.getFile().getPath());
        assertThat(mapper.map(itm, ResourceItemDTO.class).getResourceCategoriesID())
                .contains(itm.getResourceCategories().get(0).getID());
    }

    assertThat(mapper.map(cat, ResourceCategoryDTO.class).getResources().size())
            .isEqualTo(cat.getResources().size());
    assertThat(mapper.map(cat, ResourceCategoryDTO.class).getResources().get(0).getFilePath())
            .isEqualTo(cat.getResources().get(0).getFile().getPath());

}
    @Column(name = "Title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private List<ResourceItem> resources = new ArrayList<>() ;}
```

ModelMapper was not able to automatically flatten the ArrayList of ResourceCategories to an ArrayList of Integers. I attempted to create a custom mapping as follows:

```
    @Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    PropertyMap<ResourceItem, ResourceItemDTO> rItemMap = new PropertyMap<ResourceItem, ResourceItemDTO>() {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            map().setResourceCategoriesID(source.getResourceCategories().stream().map(e -> {
                return e.getID();
            }).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        }
    };

    mapper.addMappings(rItemMap);
    return mapper;
}
```

However, I receive a `Failed to configure mappings` error, with the underlying cause being a `NullPointerException`. Apparently, I approached the task incorrectly. What is the appropriate way to perform this flattening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converter to map ResourceCategories into an integer list.

```
mapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<ResourceItem, ResourceItemDTO>() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        using(ctx -> ctx.getSource().stream().map(ResourceCategory::getID).collect(Collectors.toList())
            .map().setResourceCategoriesID(source.getResourceCategories());
    }
}
```